# Webform-CiviCRM with membership payment has broken on 4.7

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I've noticed something strange on 4.7 -- webforms that integrate Webform-CiviCRM and include a payment portion are now pulling in the entire contribution page that is associated in the CiviCRM tab. Previously it would only use fields defined in the webform itself. Now I notice everything from the info/description to the Contribution page's included profiles in the payment portion of the webform.

Is this an intentional change? If so, is there a way to get the previous functionality?

UPDATE: (Further info)

- If I disable all profiles on the linked contribution page, no payment fields show up at all.
- If I enable a profile, it pulls the entire contribution page in
  rather than simply the payment fields as it used to do.
- If I disable the Membership Section on the contribution page, I get this error: `"This page does not have any price fields configured or you may not have permission for them. Please contact the site administrator for more details."` (Under "Memberships", the webform has *"Membership type" > User Select* with *"Number of Terms"* set to 1. It links to a contribution page in the "Contribution" section.)

Comment: Cross-reference to bug report on the webform_civicrm project page: https://www.drupal.org/node/2661232

Answer (score 1):

The Webform-CiviCRM module is not yet compatible with CiviCRM 4.7. You can help! See https://www.drupal.org/node/2661232